# How to create a regex matching a custom string at the beginning of line while ignoring all preceding whitespaces via ag silversearcher?

Tags: regular-expression, search, ag

Give an `example` file with the content:

```
// find me
val ignore me = "" // I should not be found
  // find me
    // find me
```

I want to find all the lines with `find me` using ag silversearcher.

Basically, it should match any line optionally starting with any white space and a double space `//`.

I know that:

```
ag ^// example
```

only yields in the first line without spaces.

For the beginning of the line I know I can use `^`, for whitespace it should be `\s`, and my custom string should either be `//` or it may need to be to escaped to: `\/\/`

That's why I thought:

```
ag ^\s*// example
ag ^\s*\/\/ example
```

Should do the trick, yet it finds also only the first line.

How can I match all the lines starting with white space and my custom string?

Comment: You forgot to enclose your regex in single quotes... `ag '^\s*//'` works fine here

Comment: @don_crissti Please add your comment as an answer for me to upvote and accept.

Comment: I'll pass and here's why: as far as I am concerned this falls in the category of "user forgot some detail" or "improper syntax"... You can always add an answer if you feel like it.